# Play Framework 2.1 - requests and loading of static content extremely slow in dev-mode

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am trying to set up my java/play project on my windows machine with win7-64bit and play-framework 2.1.5.
However I am struggling with extreme performance issues in dev-mode (play run).

When making a request, it takes about 10 seconds to load the html-page and afterwards it takes another 10 seconds for each static content (.css, .js, images) to load. Since there are a dozen static content-files, loading of the entire page takes more than 2 minutes.

This is what I have tried without any improvement:

- installing sbt and run the application with "sbt run"
- made sure that the installation-path of play doesn't contain spaces
- made sure there are read- and write rights for the play installation-folder
- tried different browsers
- increased java heapSpace and maxPermSize

However the following **does** work without any performance issues:

- when i run the application in production mode "play start" everything works fast without problems
- when I create a new default (java)-project, there is no performance-issue and the page is loaded in less then one second
- I have set up the project on other machines with the same software-environment and didn't have any performance-issues before

Can you please give me some advice how to solve this performance issue?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Alwin

Edit:
here is a screenshot of the loading-times when the problem exists: http://s3.postimg.org/fmc88zvg3/play_slow.png

here a screenshot of the loading-times on another pc with the *same* environment where there is no problem: http://s13.postimg.org/4x8q4a0nr/play_fast.png

Additionally I noticed, that while the request is executed, the cpu is constantly very busy (50% up to 90%)!

Comment: When I have breakpoints at method entry, it happens to me too. Not in play framework but in general.

Comment: so the same project runs slowly on yours and runs normally on other computers?  Are you using play run on both computers?  Have you tried with the latest play framework version and with the activator console?

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski: deleting all breakpoints doesn't make any difference

Comment: Sorry @AlwinS, I have no idea what makes your application slow down.

Comment: @alihaider: yes, it is only on particular pc where the problem exists, the project runs fine on other pcs with the same setup. Unfortunatly migrating to the latest play-version is quite a complex thing to do, since it is a rather large project, so this is not a short term solution. I have noticed, that the cpu is very busy during the request, see my edit in the question.

Comment: Maybe a DNS resolution issue? (Shouldn't be a problem for `localhost`, but maybe you are using some domain name somewhere in the markup?)

Comment: @MartinC. unfortunately not. All static files are available via localhost, and I have also tried calling "127.0.0.1" and the pc-name and got the same issues.

Comment: Any antivirus with "Internet Security" or Browser add-ons installed?

Comment: nope. It is a fresh windows installation, antivirus-software "Kaspersky" is installed, however this is also installed on the pc where it is working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now my project has been updated to the latest play version 2.3.7 and the problem is gone. Everything loads within less then one second as it is supposed to be.

This solves the problem for me, however I was not able to find out why this performance issues exist on one particular machine with play framework version 2.1.5